# IIS to SQL Server logging in with username that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows, iis

i am having no problem at all compiling/debugging my web app, but when i try to run it from my IIS server i get this error:

```
    Server Error in '/' Application.

    Login failed for user 'MLABS\STUDENT-006$'.

    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

    Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'MLABS\STUDENT-006$'.

    Source Error: 

    An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

    Stack Trace: 


    [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'MLABS\STUDENT-006$'.]
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +578
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +88
       System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6275911
       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +258
       RadarGraphInsertDLL.LOMDLL.Get_Last_Lom() in c:\users\agordon\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\lomdb\enterdata\radargraphdll\radargraphinsertdll\lomdll.cs:212
       EnterData.DataEntry.LOMForm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\LOMForm.aspx.cs:20
       System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
       System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
       System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
       System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
       System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428

    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420
```

> STUDENT-006 is my computer name it is not my username! i do not understand why it is trying to login with my computer name.

when the application is run, it immediately should pull data from the database. i have windows authentication enabled and it works without a problem when i run from dubugger, but when i try to compile i get the above error

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MLABS\STUDENT-006$` is the username that the IIS application pool is running as. You either [change the application pool user in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28WS.10%29.aspx),

> 1. Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> 2. In the Connections pane, expand the server node and click Application Pools.
> 3. On the Application Pools page, select the application pool for which you want to specify an identity, and then click Advanced
>      Settings in the Actions pane.
> 4. For the Identity property, click the ... button to open the Application Pool Identity dialog box.
> 5. If you want to use a built-in account, select the Built-in account option and select an account from the list.
> 6. If you want to use a custom identity, select the Custom account option and click Set to open the Set Credentials dialog box. Then type
>      the custom account name in the User name text box, type a password in
>      the Password text box, retype the password in the Confirm password
>      text box, and then click OK.
> 7. Click OK to dismiss the Application Pool Identity dialog box.

or you can [impersonate in web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: even so, why is it not allowing this username in there?

Comment: You can specify an account if you need to `<identity impersonate="true" userName="contoso\Jane" password="********" />`, otherwise it will use the logged in user's account.

Answer (score 1):

MLABS\STUDENT-006$ is the account that the local "NETWORK SERVICE" account looks like when connecting to other machines and how the server is registered in Active Directory.

This is what the Application Pool in IIS running under, so this connects to SQL Server.

I'd suggest using a domain account especially for this